# How to handle the Help button on CMFCPropertySheet / CMFCPropertyPage?

Tags: html-help, cmfcpropertypage

According to MSDN:

> Help in CPropertySheet is supported by the F1 key and the Help button
> only. The Help button appears in the application framework by default.
> No intervention by the user is necessary. When the user adds the help
> information for each of the pages inside the property sheet, the help
> mechanism automatically displays the help for that page when the Help
> button is clicked.

I assume the same to be true for `CMFCPropertySheet`. So I first started to try handling the `WM_HELPINFO` handler:

```
void COtherSettingsEmailInfoPage::HtmlHelp(DWORD_PTR dwData, UINT nCmd)
{
    HtmlHelp((DWORD_PTR)_T("HelpOptionsEmail.html"), HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC);

    //CMFCPropertyPage::HtmlHelp(dwData, nCmd);
}
```

Didn't work. Then I added a `IDHELP` button click handler:

```
void COtherSettingsEmailInfoPage::OnHelp()
{
    HtmlHelp((DWORD_PTR)_T("HelpOptionsEmail.html"), HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC);
}
```

Didn't work.

So how am I supposed to show the right help topic when the user presses the Help button on the sheet? Confused.

## Update

I have tried this in both the sheet and the page - doesn't work:

```
BOOL COtherSettingsEmailInfoPage::OnNotify(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    LPPSHNOTIFY lppsn = (LPPSHNOTIFY)lParam;

    if (lppsn->hdr.code == PSN_HELP)
    {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Boo2"));
    }

    return CMFCPropertyPage::OnNotify(wParam, lParam, pResult);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this sussed out in the end.

Firstly, OI had a small issue with my application where the `CWinApp` was using the wrong file name. This was caused when I made changes to my application. So I fixed that in `InitInstance`:

```
CString strHelp = GetProgramPath();
strHelp += _T("MeetSchedAssist.CHM");
free((void*)m_pszHelpFilePath);
m_pszHelpFilePath = _tcsdup(strHelp);
```

Next, I had to add a notification handler to the `CMFCPropertySheet` class:

**Header**:

```
afx_msg void OnPsnHelp(NMHDR* hdr, LRESULT* res);   // Our help button message handler
```

**Source**:

```
ON_NOTIFY(PSN_HELP, 0, &COtherSettingsEmailInfoPage::OnPsnHelp)

...
...

void COtherSettingsEmailInfoPage::OnPsnHelp(NMHDR* hdr, LRESULT* res)
{
    HtmlHelp((DWORD_PTR)_T("HelpOptionsEmail.htm"), HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC);
}
```

Now it correctly shows the help topic.